# Unable to alter table with unique constrain using Sequel and Sqlite3

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sequel, padrino

These are my migrations for the table *users_hobbies*:

Create:

```
Sequel.migration do
  up do
    create_table :users_hobbies do
      Integer :user_id
      Integer :hobby_id
    end
  end

  down do
    drop_table :users_hobbies
  end
end
```

Alter:

```
Sequel.migration do
  up do
    alter_table :users_hobbies do
      unique [:user_id, :hobby_id]
    end
  end

  down do
  end
end
```

When I did the second migration I got the following error, any ideas?

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'unique' for #<Sequel::Schema::AlterTableGenerator:0x007fba1aea7c30>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unique` is only defined in `create_table` blocks.  In `alter_table` blocks, you need to use `add_unique_constraint`.

Comment: I somehow didn't figure this out for so long that I chose to edit the old migration :D. Sad. Anyways, thanks!